# jQuery load callback not called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to load html content dynamically with jQuery:

```
$('panel').load('pages/Panel.html', function() {
    alert("Load was performed.");
});
```

The Panel.html is a simple HTML:

```
<div>Hello</div>
```

The panel HTML loads successfully but the load callback is never called.
Tried IE8/9/10 and nothing worked.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: It's extremely hard to say without more information. It could be that you have multiple 'panel' elements on the page and subsequent attempts to load the content into them are failing. Try a more specific selector and see if that helps (e.g. `$('#my-panel').load...`)

Comment: you should avoid alerts and use `console.log()` and use a tool like chrome for debugging.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The actual name from my code is unique (verified that). The content is loaded fine, but the callback is not (I've put a breakpoint and I never reach it).

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't an element `panel` in your DOM. So may be this one `$('panel')` should be something like `$('.panel')`?

But it should work as well with `$('panel')`...

So by modifing it this way

```
$('panel').load('pages/Panel.html', function(me)
{
    console.info(me);
    alert("Load was performed.");
});
```

Does console.info returns something?

It should pass the html just appended to the element

Comment: The id is fine since I see that the content is loaded.

Comment: Ok so by trying to console the html appended as I suggest what do u get?

Comment: Or try to check if for some reason `alert` was freezed. What do `console.info(typeof alert);` returns?

Comment: The callback is not called so I don't even get to the alert. I tried also the console stuff but I do not reach this code.

Comment: Hmm maybe some js problem inside Panel.html. Could you please provide more code in your question in order to help someone to find the problem?

Comment: My Panel.html is a simple <div>hello</div> :-)

Comment: Ok I suggest you to post other code and what you've tried. Otherwise it isn't possible and become the wheel of fortune...

Comment: I can't post the entire code since it is based on thousands of code lines. I've updated the question with the Panel.html content. 
Thanks!